# Drupal Views - Multiple Vocabulary Arguments / Filter

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to setup a view that will need both arguments to be from different vocabularies and having some trouble.

I have a list of countries and a list of topics, so I would want something like this:

page/Argentina/25

This actually seems to work because I can see it pull the title properly, however it is not grabbing any of the 2nd parameter nodes as if no nodes have that category selected.

The strange thing is when I display the TermID field for each node, it lists the ID of the first parameter. I can also see this in the query it gives:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   node.title AS node_title,
   node.language AS node_language,
   node.vid AS node_vid
 FROM d6_node node 
 LEFT JOIN d6_term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid
 INNER JOIN d6_term_data term_data ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
 WHERE (node.type in ('listings')) AND (term_data.name = 'Argentina') AND (term_node.tid = 25)
```

Which I think would make sense since it is only joining with the 1st term

Is this possible?

Comment: If you look at the WHERE clause, it has 'WHERE (node.type in ('listings')) AND (term_data.name = 'Argentina') AND (term_node.tid = 25)'.  You probably aren't looking for listings that have both 'Argentina' AND tid 25, are you?  It sounds from your description that you want one OR the other....  That might be your problem.  You want 'OR' not 'AND'